# Extracting SharePoint data on daily basis

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, sharepoint, export

I want to export my SharePoint document library data on daily basis and csv file need to be save as naming convention as `Dataname_yyyyMMdd`. As per my below script, it need to export data from the sharepoint library into one CSV file as name `Data_yyyyMMdd`. Then it need to imports the data from `Data_yyyyMMdd` and adds "header" to the file and then export to new final output CSV as name "DataName_yyyyMMdd".

While running the script i am getting only one file as `Data_yyyyMMdd`. The data from file was not importing to final csv file and its not generating the final output file `DataName_yyyyMMdd`. Please correct me if doing wrong in script. Please share me correct script.

Powershell script

```
$web = get-spweb $siteUrl
$caseLib = $web.lists | where {$_.title -eq $listTitle}
$query=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='LinkFilename'/><FieldRef Name='DocumentSetDescription'/>"
$query.RowLimit=5000

do

$ListName1 = "Data"
$ExportFolder1 = “C:\Users\”
$ExportName1 = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”
$ExportPath1 = $ExportFolder1 + $ListName1 + $ExportName1 + “.csv”
$ListName = "Dataname_"
$ExportFolder = “C:\Users\csv\”
$ExportName = Get-Date -f “yyyyMMdd”
$ExportPath = $ExportFolder + $ListName + $ExportName + “.csv”
{
$caseLibItems=$caseLib.GetItems($query)
$query.ListItemCollectionPosition=$caseLibItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
$listItemsTotal = $caseLibItems.Count
$x = 0
for($x=0;$x -lt $listItemsTotal; $x++)
{
    $Description = $caseLibItems[$x]["DocumentSetDescription"]
    $str = ""
    if('$Description' -ne $null)
    {
        $Description = $Description -replace "`n"," " -replace "`r"," "
        $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString() + '}' + $Description
    }
    else
    {
        $str = $caseLibItems[$x]["LinkFilename"].ToString()
    }

Write-Output $str | Out-File $ExportPath1 -Append  
}

} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

Import-csv $ExportPath1 -delimiter "}" -Header "Number", "Description"  | export-csv $ExportPath -NoTypeInformation  

Write-Host "Exiting"
```